# Stack Overflow for Teams with strict data protection

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

We are a German insurance company with strict data protection rules. Usually we avoid anything that cannot be run on-premises -- at least our data should not leave the European Union.

As I understand, Stack Overflow does not offer a solution for us if we do not have 500+ users. This is sad because it implies that we need to use some Stack Overflow clone until some day Stack Overflow enlarges its portfolio.

What could be a feasible solution for a case like ours?

Comment: I talked to a salesperson, and it was made pretty clear that we cannot buy the product for 150 users.

Comment: I think you already know the answer, but here goes: unless SO decides to offer a stand-alone Teams version or lower the user requirements for Enterprise, you will have to find a different vendor. [Related post on the difference between and reasoning behind both products](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377523)

Comment: @Stijn Yes, but this is difficult. There is a range of different vendors, it is difficult to say which product is mature enough (and does not vanish in the next 1-2 years), and if SO eventually hears my plea, we may need to migrate from product XY to SO.